# Pushing a UITabBarController with a UINavigationBar onto an existing UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Okay I am working on a group project and what we are trying to do is create a "Results Screen" which has It's Own UINavigation and contains two TabBars in it. We are trying push that ontop of an existing UINavigation. Right now at the moment of this code. We have our main App Delegate and in it we instantiate a beginning navigation and tabbar.

```
startTabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:templatesVC,recentJobsVC,profileVC,aboutVC,nil]; 

 startTabBarController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"D2P_Logo2.png"]];
 startTabBarController.navigationItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 UIBarButtonItem *tempRightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" 
                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                    target:self 
                    action:@selector(makeJob)]; 
 [startTabBarController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:tempRightBarButton];

 [mainNavBar pushViewController:startTabBarController animated:NO];

 [window addSubview:mainNavBar.view];
```

Now what we want to do is add another Tab Bar on top with a segmented navigation controller and a tab bar controller.

At the moment were are trying a UIViewController without a xib to do this. I've tried various methods but all that has come up is a blank screen.

In Terms of Layout of what we have we have a Navigation Controller and on it's stack is a UITabBarController -> UITableViewController -> UITableViewController and we want to add on top of that a UIViewController with a UINavigationController and UITabBarController in that.

Any Advice would greaty be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO - this seems to be your first question?  Just a tip - the editor provides "code" tags to make your code easier to read.  It even includes auto-syntax highlighting.  May I suggest you edit this post and try that?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found a solution. Ended up using a ModelViewController and then had some issues with a white bar which I solved by searching around these very forums and found out that I just had to hide the status bar before showing the ModelViewController and showing it after it was loaded.

Thanks anyways though.